# How to declare external typescript types in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, react-admin, kotlin-js

I need to access a Typescript library (react-admin) from kotlin-js
In particular this types definitions

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/ra-core/src/types.ts

How do I declare in kotlinjs for example the following types ?

```js
export type AuthProvider = {
    login: (params: any) => Promise<any>;
    logout: (params: any) => Promise<void | false | string>;
    checkAuth: (params: any) => Promise<void>;
    checkError: (error: any) => Promise<void>;
    getIdentity?: () => Promise<UserIdentity>;
    getPermissions: (params: any) => Promise<any>;
    [key: string]: any;
};




export type DataProvider<ResourceType extends string = string> = {
    getList: <RecordType extends RaRecord = any>(
        resource: ResourceType,
        params: GetListParams
    ) => Promise<GetListResult<RecordType>>;

    getOne: <RecordType extends RaRecord = any>(
        resource: ResourceType,
        params: GetOneParams
    ) => Promise<GetOneResult<RecordType>>;


// etc etc ...

}
```

thanks